# What collection class should we use to manage and merge list of objects using C#?

Tags: c#, .net, collections

I'm looking for a collection to manage and merge list of objects using C# ? Do you know where I can find a good tutorial abour collections ?

Actally I'm looking to merge two or three list of objects/entities. These lists can contains the same object (identical id). The merged list should contain only one version of each object/entities. Then I should order the list on a property.

Comment: Your question is not clear. What type of collections are you using currently. Show some sample data and a desired result.

Comment: For the reason of needing distinct items in the collection, I recommend you look into Dictionary<T>.

Comment: I didn't choose a collection yet. I'm looking for a good documentation about it first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `HashSet<T>` with a custom `IEqualityComparer<T>`. Or you could use a `Dictionary<T1, T2>` where `T1` is your ID.

Comment: How do you know that? Where can I find a good documentation about collection and properties of these collections?

Comment: From MSDN: "The HashSet<T> class provides high-performance set operations. A set is a collection that contains no duplicate elements, and whose elements are in no particular order."  So would a HashSet be an invalid choice given there may (I think) be duplicates?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how you want to merge your collections, you could use any collection that implements `IEnumerable<T>`, as this interface provides the [`Union(IEnumerable<T>)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341731.aspx) method that "merges" and removes duplicates.

You then might want to implement `IEqualityComparer<T>` to compare your objects using their identity (ID) property.

Comment: Once you've done this, you can then use Linq's `OrderBy` to order the results however you like...